# error in reading g-data

Tags: android, calendar

From different post i have concluded that insertion, deletion and updation in Calendar is only  possible by using g-data.

Therefore i am using g-data 1.41.3 with android 1.5 api level 3.

Problem is that , i am using the following code.

```
    1    // Send the request and receive the response:
    2   // the code is use for reading Calendar Content
    3  // feedUrl = http://209.85.132.104/calendar/feeds/androidshma@gmail.com/allcalendars/full        
    4   
    5           CalendarFeed resultFeed = service.getFeed(feedUrl, CalendarFeed.class);
    6    
    7           // Print the title of each calendar
    8           for (int i = 0; i < resultFeed.getEntries().size(); i++) {
    9               CalendarEntry entry = resultFeed.getEntries().get(i);
    10              System.out.println("\t" + entry.getTitle().getPlainText());
    11          }
```

problem is that application throwing exception on line no. 5.
Exception is as follow:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: com.google.gdata.util.common.xml.parsing.SecureGenericXMLFactory$SecureSAXParserFactory
```

and in different forum it is mention that No XSchema support in Android 1.0. Maybe later version.

how i can read calendar contents?
it is noted that without android its working fine.

Comment: as above code is gdata sample code. present in CalendarFeedDemo.java.
if i run it through ant its running perfectly. But making problem in android.

Answer (score 0):

till now gdata not supported on android.
http://code.google.com/p/android-gdata/

no g data libraries available.